# working with SSasymp in r

Tags: r

I think I don't get how to use the SSasymp function in r. I want to make an asymptotic function for my project.

---

I tried this:

```
c <- seq(0,200,0.5)
d <- SSasymp(c, 500, 0, -log(50))
plot(c,d, type = "l")
```

---

`log(50)` should be the natural Logarithm of the rate constant. So at this x value (50) the half of the maximum y value is reached. Am I right? This should be 250 (500/2), but in my case I get y = 316. 
So, what have I done wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check how my own similar question has been answered by another user: [plotting lrc in SSasymp in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49752514/plotting-lrc-in-ssasymp-in-r)

You will get the value of

```
y = 250
```

for the value of

`x = log(2) / exp(lrc = -log(50))`